# Load payment provider on top

Tags: payment, navigation, amazon-payment

let me explain what my issue is. I load magento into an iFrame to integrate the store into a webpage. This works like charm until it comes to amazon pay or unzer for example. Due to the iFrame, the payment fails or does not load at all  (for security reasons).

My question is, if there is any option to breakout of the iFrame and load the new location on top if we leave the magento store and load a payment provider.

I would be very grateful for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by removing the iFrame on the checkout page and modifications on the website .htaccess (see my post below)

[Load magento via .htaccess RewriteRule](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/359662/load-magento-via-htaccess-rewriterule)